# Fast DES for Python

Tags: python, des

i am searching for compiled des implementation for python. M2Crypto don't work for me with error message "ImportError: DLL load failed:". OpenSSLLight installed.

Edit: ok, fixed with M2Crypto. For some reasons, if you select during the installation of SSLLight that the libraries should be placed in the program directory, they are not recognised by programs. I reinstalled openssllight with placing the libs into windows dir, and now M2Crypto loads.

Answer (score 0):

[Pycrypto](http://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/) supports DES/DES3 and has [prebuilt Windows installers from Voidspace](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/modules.shtml#pycrypto). Quick example:

```
from Crypto.Cipher import DES
des = DES.new('13371337', DES.MODE_ECB)
des.encrypt('plaintxt')

'\xeb\x9d\xe7~&\xb4fp'
```